# le plus tôt (que) possible

Tags: usage

J'ai entendu quelqu'un employer :

> ...le plus tôt **que** possible.

Est-ce un *que* facultatif ?

Y a-t-il une différence avec

> ...le plus tôt possible.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu as dû mal entendre.

C'est soit:

> le plus tôt possible

soit

> aussitôt que possible.

On rencontre néanmoins quelques rares *le plus tôt que possible*, il semble s'agir d'un régionalisme (Alsace).

Comment: Probablement la traduction littérale de "so schnell wie möglich"

Comment: Merci @jlliagre. En effet la personne qui a utilisé cette la tournure avec que vient d'Afrique (étudiée dans une école francophone je crois).